# Manipulate the order of components render in react

Tags: reactjs, settimeout, setinterval, react-props

I have a functional component which has a class based component as its subcomponent. The value of the state in the class component is passed through this.props from functional component to the class component as below:

```
this.state = {
  body: this.props.initialValue ? this.props.initialValue : ' '
}
```

The problem is that the class component keeps loading before the functional component and as a result the initial body value is equal to empty. I tried setInterval() on componentDidMount(), but it did not work. Is there any way so I could load the class component after the functional component?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should use getDerivedStateFromProps lifecycle to update state based on props

Comment: `const C = (props) => <><A value={props.value}/><B/></>;` Obviously, A will render before C, because C's render depends on A. `componentDidMount` of A will run after A renders. `componentDidMount` of C will render after `componentDidMount` of A. You can't do much here without changing the component arrangement. Best is if you show a loader: Like a spinner or something?